# What is the -sk ending for ssh key types?

Tags: ssh

`ssh-keygen` has the following options for a key type (`-t`):

`dsa | ecdsa | ecdsa-sk | ed25519 | ed25519-sk | rsa`

I am not familiar with the `-sk` notation and it's not explained in the man page.

What does it mean?

Comment: It's not explained, but at least one option under CERTIFICATES is described as limited to "the FIDO authenticator algorithms ecdsa-sk and ed25519-sk"

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In OpenSSH FIDO devices are supported by new public
key types "ecdsa-sk" and "ed25519-sk", along with corresponding
certificate types.

To quote:

> ### FIDO/U2F Support
>
> This release adds support for FIDO/U2F hardware authenticators to
> OpenSSH. U2F/FIDO are open standards for inexpensive two-factor
> authentication hardware that are widely used for website
> authentication.  In OpenSSH FIDO devices are supported by new public
> key types "ecdsa-sk" and "ed25519-sk", along with corresponding
> certificate types.

Source: https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.2

These "-sk" variants can only be created with a YubiKey or compatible FIDO/U2F token and the token is required to use the private key.

Comment: From my understanding these -sk variants can only be created with a YubiKey or compatible FIDO/U2F token and the token is required to use the private key. This could be clearer in your answer.

Answer (score 33):

`-sk` SSH key-pairs can be either `ecdsa-sk` or `ed25519-sk`. The `-sk` extension stands for security key. Note that an ed25519-sk key-pair is only supported by new YubiKeys with firmware 5.2.3 or higher which supports FIDO2. This means YubiKeys with firmware below 5.2.3 are only compatible with ecdsa-sk key-pairs. If possible, generate an `ed25519-sk` SSH key-pair for this reason. Source: https://cryptsus.com/blog/how-to-configure-openssh-with-yubikey-security-keys-u2f-otp-authentication-ed25519-sk-ecdsa-sk-on-ubuntu-18.04.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Great first answer - I would however note that there are [problems with DSA and ECDSA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821736/whats-the-difference-between-id-rsa-pub-and-id-dsa-pub/27855045#27855045). ED25519 is definitely the preferred of the two.

Comment: @MechMK1 I agree. If you have the choice use EdDSA. On the other hand, DSA only requires good random numbers so for many applications it's fine. And especially a Yubikey will probably have a good hardware based rng and no issues.

Comment: DSA should not be used because it is not secure. In versions > 7 of OpenSSH dsa algorithms are deprecated. So there is no need to use dsa keys.

Comment: The original source from which you copied-and-pasted parts of your answer has a link behind "for this reason", which explains *why* one should generate `ed25519-sk` keys. Your answer make a point only for `ecdsa-sk` keys (namely, compatibility).

Comment: @Anonymous20DB28 seems like you missed the point a bit... E/C/DSA, or Elliptical Curve DSA, shares the same parametric flaw as exponential DSA, and aside from being very vulnerable to less than stellar RNG, can be made entirely solvable (and thus useless) in multiple scenarios (static k value for example). Whenever possible, Ed25519 should be used instead, and if not possible, a 4096-bit RSA key is preferred to any form of DSA.